# gpo task scheduler powershell script

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, gpo

I have a problem with my GPO (Group Policy Object). When I run my script manually, it works fine, but when I try to run it through GPO, it doesn't work. I have already given the necessary write permissions to my account, but the issue persists.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvZfl.png)

I changed the SMB (Server Message Block) file share links to allow writing and reading. However, despite this modification, the script still doesn't work properly when executed via the GPO.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDFcf.png)

Comment: You have to run as an Admin.  Try right click PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/grouppolicy/?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Comment: I run the script using my admin account.

Comment: @Khalis that's not what he suggested. He suggested the "Run as administrator" option, which indeed requires an admin account. However just running it from an admin account does not guarantee it is "Ran as administrator" unless you have disabled UAC, in which case I'd say undo that bad configuration.

Comment: Now when it comes to your scheduled task, this would be "run with highest privileges"

Comment: I scheduled task you would need to start the task with an account.  For admin to work over a network the local and remote machines need to be in the same Group and the user Account (or Admin) needs to be a network account.  Not an account on just local machine.

Comment: I would like to explain that I'm running the script with a domain administrator account that has all the necessary rights, so I don't believe that's the issue.